# Making a field "blank=False" in production

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have deployed my Django website but just now realized that I didn't make one of the fields compulsory. For the field it is currently,

> blank=True, null=True

Now if I go ahead and change it to

> blank=False

will there be any effect on the database and already existing data in it?

Comment: you have to set `null=False` too and `syncdb` . migrate may be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `blank` is enforced solely at the application level.

Comment: Is it! Let me try the same. Will accept your answer after trying, in a while.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank :

- "blank" is about the form validation; you can change this at any time without affecting
  your database.
- "null" is about the storage in the database, not about form validation

So if you change from "blank=True, null=True" to "blank=False", you'll still be able to store null values in the table--but you won't have a way to actually get those null values into the database, since your forms will require input.

This might be exactly what you want (and no db migration would be needed).

If you want to get existing null values out of your database, update your data, then set both blank and null to False. At that point, though, you'd need to do a database migration (via South or by just directly changing your database with an ALTER TABLE ... ALTER command).